# {INCLUDETEXT} does not work with the relative path created with {filename} in word. {INCLUDEPICUTRE} works fine, though

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using the method proposed by @macropod to use relative path to link the external text in word.

The post of macropod is this one:

https://forums.windowssecrets.com/showthread.php/154379-Word-Fields-and-Relative-Paths-to-External-Files

The code:

```
{INCLUDETEXT "{filename\*Lower\*MERGEFORMAT}\\..\\PINFO\\a.txt"\* MERGEFORMAT}
```

Gave me an error message:

> Error! Not a valid filename.

However, the code:

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE "{filename\*Lower\*MERGEFORMAT}\\..\\PINFO\\a.png"\* MERGEFORMAT}
```

worked perfectly in my word document.

Does anyone have some idea why this happened? I am using Word 2016.

Comment: Not sure why the "\\" disappears, the code should be {INCLUDETEXT "{filename\\*Lower\\*MERGEFORMAT}\\\\..\\\\PINFO\\\\a.txt"\\* MERGEFORMAT}

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please refer to the documentation on [formatting](https://superuser.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting code in questions on Super User. You referenced "the method proposed by @macropod". It may be relevant to see that method. Please [edit] your question and add a link.

Comment: It could be because the { filename } field should really contain the \\p switch which means that the path is included, i.e. { filename \p } (there should be a backslash before the "p" that may go missing in this comment. The \*Lower and \*Mergeformat are not really needed on a Windows machine. If the "p" switch isn't included, Word may assume a certain path. It's possible that it makes a different assumption for INCLUDETEXT and INCLUDEPICTURE.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a bug in Word.  Don't worry I'm giving you a solution here!

While you're inter-working with 2 documents that one contains the 'includetext' to another document, please **OPEN THESE 2 FILES AT THE SAME TIME BUT DO NOT SAVE THE SOURCE FILE THAT YOU ARE REFERRING TO**.

Once all the fields are up-to-date, you are then free to edit and save the source file.  But don't go back again to update these fields as they will cause the same error again.